# LINQ-to-sql + C#. Only retrieve some columns from table to gridview

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I try to pull some data and insert it into a gridview. But I must be doing something wrong since I can only select a single column. If I try to get both first and lastname then they will just be inserted into the same td in the gridview.

Method so far is:

```
public string[] ShowName()

    {
        LinqToEbuboo_20DataContext db = new LinqToEbuboo_20DataContext();
        var myusers = from u in db.db_users
            where u.uid > 13
            select u.firstname;

            return myusers.ToArray();
    }
```

I am fairly unfamiliar with both C# and LINQ (and gridviews for that sake) so it is probably a fairly simple problem.

It is build like this:

```
1) aspx (frontend)
2) webservice
3) C# (business logic)
4) database
```

The method posted here is in Business Layer and will be called from the webservive that will return the result to the frontend where the result will be bound to a gridview like this:

```
GridView1.DataSource = s.showemail();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

----------(end of original question)--------------------

Follow-up on answers:
This is what I have build now based on input. It still does not work. From aspx where I try to set the datasource for the gridview an error will show. Something with a reference that is needed. But when trying to create it I cannot due to a loop in references...

user.cs

```
namespace Ebuboo
{
  public class User
  {
    public PersonName[] ListStrangers()
    {
      LinqToEbuboo_20DataContext db = new LinqToEbuboo_20DataContext();
      var myusers = from u in db.db_users
      where u.uid > 12
      select new PersonName { FirstName = u.firstname, LastName = u.lastname };
        return myusers.ToArray();
      }
    }
  }
  public class PersonName
  {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
  }
}
```

The ListStrangers() is called from a webservice:

```
  [WebMethod]
  public PersonName[] ws_listUsers()
  {
    User u = new User();
    return u.ListStrangers();
  }
```

And the webservice is called from an aspx that try to bind the result to a gridview:

```
  // create instance of webservice
  Ebuboo_WS.Service1 s = new Ebuboo_WS.Service1();

  // Bind and output result in Gridview
  GvListUsers.DataSource = s.ws_listUsers();
  GvListUsers.DataBind();
```

Br. Anders

Comment: If you're "fairly unfamiliar with both C# and LINQ (and gridviews for that sake)", why not go buy a book, or read the MSDN documentation?

Comment: Hi. I got the "Programming C# 3.0" by Jesse Liberty. I work with php on linux servers full time but have just started to look into Microsoft technologies. C# aint the only new thing. Most are new, like C#, LINQ, all of the .net framework and Visual Studio. It is just to big a mounthfull to grasp and understand in one go. But I am well manared and only ask questions when I get stuck.

Comment: It seems as I cannot just return PersonName[]. I tried to write in my question how I done it. If you can se a mistake in it I will apreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) from your function so you can't get multiple columns that way.

You would need to do something like this where you create a type that holds the results of your query (the multiple columns) so that you can return them from a function.

```
public PersonName[] ShowName()
{
    LinqToEbuboo_20DataContext db = new LinqToEbuboo_20DataContext();
    var myusers = from u in db.db_users
                  where u.uid > 13
                  select new PersonName { FirstName = u.firstname, LastName = u.lastname };
    return myusers.ToArray();
}

public class PersonName {
    public string FirstName { get; set; };
    public string LastName { get; set; };
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have done a bit of reading and are back with Visual Studio. I may be doing this wrong. I have one file called user.cs with a user-class followed by your PersonName-class with the get/set. In the User-class I have the method with the LINQ that returns PersonName[]. Is this correct? I ask since I get an error when trying to to the databind to the gridview (Error The type 'Ebuboo_BL.PersonName' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Ebuboo_BL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'....)

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an Anonymous Type in your query:

```
LinqToEbuboo_20DataContext db = new LinqToEbuboo_20DataContext();
var myusers = from u in db.db_users
    where u.uid > 13
    select new { u.firstname, u.lastname };
```

However, as Jason Punyon wrote, you can't return Anonymous Types from your method.